# How to set QT_QPA_PLATFORM for test

Tags: cmake, qttest

I have some Qt tests that pop up a window when run. Therefore i want to add possibility to disable their rendering.Can I set in cmake environment variable QT_QPA_PLATFORM to offscreeen only for test?

Comment: Have you seen `set_tests_properties` and the `ENVIRONMENT` test property?

Comment: I try set_tests_properties(tests PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen")  but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I use it for my tests and that's the way to go:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen executable
```

This is POSIX-compatible, so thiw will also work on Windows.